# How do I calculate FPS from data in a .mov file?

Tags: file, frame-rate, quicktime

I've been writing a program in C# that reads a `.mov` file. I'm able to parse through the entire thing, ignoring chunks I don't understand, and grabbing relevant info from chunks that I do.

What I'm trying to do is get the FPS from the file, but getting it hasn't been straightforward. I assume because the format can store many movies at different rates.

If someone could point me in the right direction, like which chunks (atoms) should I be looking at? I thought it was `stts`, but not all `.mov` files contain that chunk!

Answer (score 1):

I was mistaken. The stts atom is always there, and that is where you get the information to calculate the FPS. The following code hasn't be thoroughly tested, but it did work with all the .mov files I have.

```
void ReadSTTS(BinaryReader reader)
{
    int versionAndFlags = reader.ReadInt32(true);
    int nEntries = reader.ReadInt32(true);

    int sampleCount = 0;
    int sampleDuration = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nEntries; i++)
    {
        sampleCount += reader.ReadInt32(true);
        sampleDuration += reader.ReadInt32(true);
    }

    FPS = (float)Math.Round((float)mediaTimeScale / ((float)mediaDuration / (float)sampleCount), 2);
}
```

mediaTimeScale and mediaDuration both come from the mvhd atom. ReadInt32(true) is an extension that changes the endianness, since I'm reading the .mov on a windows machine.